# Does Nova spoil Legacy?

Tags: starcraft-2, nova-covert-ops

I'm not finished playing the single player campaign of Legacy of the Void, but I was thinking about playing Nova Covert Ops on a different computer (e.g. on the road), but I'm worried about spoilers for the LotV story whilst playing Nova. Are there any? Or does it take place in the past or something so there isn't any spoiler?

Comment: I think covert ops tells nova's story, so it comes before WoL and won't really spoil anything unless you consider knowing the back stories of characters spoilers

Comment: @Aequitas Covert Ops tells Nova's story definitely after WoL

Answer (score 3):

Judging by 6 missions (last 3 are not released yet), the story of Nova: Covert Ops does not overlap the main storyline of the trilogy. Covert Ops take place either after or during Legacy of the Void.

Nova does meet a couple of characters from the main story, though, and while Nova does not know them, it is assumed that the player does. If you are pretty far through LotV (say, you have unlocked all units), it is OK to start Covert Ops.